# Help identifying tablet

Tags: hardware, tablet

I don't know if here is the right place to put this but I need your help identifying what I believe is a Chinese tablet that a friend of mine received as a gift.

The problem is that it is locked in the boot loading process (it only displays Android on screen) and I need to reinstall it. The only information I have is what dmesg returned when connected via USB

```
:~$ dmesg | tail
[161396.250396] usb 2-1.1: Product: Android
[161396.250399] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: USB Developer
[161396.250401] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 20080411d412e5d
[161401.258415] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[161402.252904] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access USB 2.0 USB Flash Driver 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[161402.253268] scsi 10:0:0:1: Direct-Access USB 2.0 USB Flash Driver 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[161402.254146] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
[161402.254372] sd 10:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg10 type 0
[161402.257914] sd 10:0:0:1: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
[161402.260390] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I already try to find the serial number and the manufacturer on Google but I can't find anything related. I took some pictures from the tablet and the box

**Box**

[image: box]

**Front**
[image: front]

**Back**
[image: back]

Thanks

Comment: I've no idea what it is, but you should plug it in to USB, run `lsusb` on your PC, and [edit] the result into your question. That's more likely to help identify it.

Comment: Hi, the lsusb gives this 

`Bus 002 Device 017: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc.`

the lsusb -v returns this http://pastebin.com/SZtEUfqN

Answer (score 1):

Using ADB (comment if you need help getting that setup):

Connect your device to your computer

On the command line in the directory containing adb.exe

Use this command: `adb connect localhost:5555`

(assuming you are on windows, let me know if otherwise) Then do: `adb bugreport > report.txt`

That should give you a whole bunch of info in a txt file in the same directory you executed the command. In the file you can search with a text editor (notepad for example) for all the info your heart could desire.

Comment: Hi, I'm on Linux but I manage to run the command and now I have a lot of info that I don't understand haha but because of your suggestion I made an adb and a lot of readeing and with a `adb shell getprop` now I have what I need to re install the tablet or at least more info than what I already have :D thanks!

Comment: BTW this is the  result of adb shell getprop -> http://pastebin.com/08r5nvie

Comment: I found a solution to the boot loading loop [here](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/79633-modcwm-recovery-6028-for-a13-tablets-v2a/). It was matter of install CWM, boot in to recovery and wipe cache/factory reset. Now it boot normaly :D